# Console windows, similar to windows "cmd.exe"

Tags: java, windows, console

I've recently coded a "Battleship" program, and right now busy improving the user friendliness (if that is a proper word in english ^^). Considering that you can start a server, I'd like to add some sort of server console, where you get status reports (e.g. "Player 1 connected") and can type in commands, such as "stop" to shut the server down.

Now unfortunately, after browsing several google results & stackoverflow posts, I have the impression that there is no easy way to access a console window similar to windows' command line (cmd.exe) - is that correct? Obviously, I could just create a JFrame with a JTextField for input and an ineditable JTextArea for output, but I don't feel like that's very elegant, considering that most of what I'm printing out with `System.out.println()` so far should appear there.

Any ideas ...?

Comment: The way you would have to go is probably split server and client: The server then outputs its stuff into the system's console - clients then connect to the server. Someone hosting a game would then start a server and connect to `localhost` with a client instance. If you also want a mode where no other player has to connect to play, make it a special server mode or ship the server code with the client and start a embedded server instance.

Comment: in fact, server & client ARE separated. From the main menu, you can choose "host" or "join" - if you click "host", the server class + the main program will be launched with localhost (only with "join") & the specified port as parameters (both as separate threads)
once I'll add AI, I'll just make the player host a server, and then add some sort of "create AI" button that will create an AI player that joins the server on localhost.

anyhow, that wasn't really the question - currently, all server status reports are sent via `System.out.println()`, but that isn't available outside of eclipse.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  If you start the Java application with `java` rather than `javaw` then you get a console window exactly like the one cmd.exe uses.

Answer (score 1):

## How common is a "console" with `JTextArea` and `JTextField`?

If you look at for example Minecraft, you can see that a `JFrame` with a `JTextField` for entering the next command and an ineditable `JTextArea` are actually quite common.

You can even intercept `System.out.println()`, or any use of `System.out` actually, by calling `System.setOut()` to set it to your own `PrintStream` which would append text to the forementioned `JTextArea`.

However, there are a few things to consider.

## Do you really want the server to depend on Swing?

When you use a `JFrame` with a `JTextField` and a `JTextArea` for the server console, the server cannot run in a headless environment. Proper servers can run in headless environments without a GUI, they can be started on server operating systems using the corresponding infrastructure like `init.d` (resp. be run as Windows service).

This doesn't mean that you can't use Swing at all. But you should consider the Strategy design pattern and give the user the control whether the Swing UI should be started for the server, or it should simply use `stdin` and `stderr`. The Swing UI would also be more difficult for users to automate. They could simply pipe a command sequence to `stdin` automatically from a script. With graphical user interfaces, such automation becomes more difficult.

## Java Readline Libraries

When you use `stdin` / `stderr` for the sever control, you might want to give your users comfort by using a readline library that simulates some of the behavior of GNU readline.

## `System.out` is NOT for logging. Use `System.err` instead.

It is a common mistake to use `System.out` for logging. But that's not what `System.out` is for. `System.out` (`stdout`) is for the program's output. For example, that's where `ls` or `dir` print the files of the current directory. Messages which do not comprise the primary output of your program should go on `System.err` instead.

## Consider a logging framework

Some of the things that you want to achieve might already be available in a logging framework. There's one that comes with Java, `java.util.logging`, and there are several more frameworks out in the wild. Simply printing to `System.err`, or even worse `System.out`, is considered a very weak, poor form of logging, and complex applications quickly outgrow their demands for logging, making `System.err` pretty unsatisfactory.